# How do I fix my MySQL select statement to get a correct result

Tags: mysql

How to get a correct result for my select statement below

```
SELECT * FROM ads 
WHERE ad_status='1' 
AND ad_region='Location One' OR ad_region='Location Two' OR ad_region='Location Three' 
AND ad_type='For Rent' 
ORDER BY ad_id 
DESC LIMIT 10
```

This statement will return to all of `ad_type` (For Rent, Wanted, For Sale, etc), but I want `For Rent` only.

I thought the problem is on `ad_region` because have `OR`. If without 'OR' (single location) the result is correct.

Let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try parenthesizing your `OR` section:

```
SELECT * FROM ads 
WHERE ad_status='1' 
AND ( ad_region='Location One' OR
      ad_region='Location Two' OR
      ad_region='Location Three' )
AND ad_type='For Rent' 
ORDER BY ad_id 
DESC LIMIT 10
```

`AND` has a higher precedence than `OR` as shown [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) so what you have in your question is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM ads 
WHERE (ad_status='1' AND ad_region='Location One')
OR ad_region='Location Two'
OR (ad_region='Location Three' AND ad_type='For Rent')
ORDER BY ad_id 
DESC LIMIT 10
```

which will give you everything from location 1 with an ad status of 1, plus everything from location 2 plus all rental ads from location 3.

Comment: I owe you a cup of coffee. Nice explanation.

Comment: Beer would be be better but I suppose it doesn't matter if it's virtual :-)

Answer (score 5):

You need to put `OR` condition into brackets or use `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM ads 
WHERE 
    ad_status='1' 
  AND 
    ad_region IN ('Location One', 'Location Two', 'Location Three')     
  AND 
    ad_type='For Rent' 
ORDER BY ad_id 
DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 2):

your logic is not entirely clear.  You need to enclose the logically subordinate clauses in parentheses in order to let MySQL know what you actually want.

Do you want

```
ad_status='1'
    AND (ad_region='Location One' OR ad_region='Location Two' OR ad_region='Location Three')
    AND ad_type='For Rent'
```

?

If you do, you're probably better off using `IN()`, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ads 
WHERE ad_status='1'
    AND ad_region IN ('Location One', 'Location Two', 'Location Three')
    AND ad_type='For Rent' 
ORDER BY ad_id 
DESC LIMIT 10
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put brackets around your 3rd line, i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM ads 
WHERE ad_status='1' 
AND (ad_region='Location One' OR ad_region='Location Two' OR ad_region='Location Three')
AND ad_type='For Rent' 
ORDER BY ad_id 
DESC LIMIT 10
```

You could also use an "in" but I try stay away from these since they are generally quite slow.